# By checking the element type in a list, returns wrong value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, types

There are 2 lists, one with dict inside and snother with int

```
values_dict = [{'other clicks': 497, 'photo view': 509, 'link clicks': 49}]

values_int = [1055]
```

I have to first check the type of element inside and then make something else

So, the most easy way:

```
for v in values_dict:
    if type(v) == dict:
        print('1')
    elif type(v) != dict:
        print('2')
```

I have no idea why, but it returns '2', like there is not a dict inside values_dict variable.

However,

```
for v in values_dict:
    print(type(v))
```

Returns `<class 'dict'>`

I have tried like this

```
for v in values_dict:
    if isinstance(value, type(dict)) is True:
        print('1')
    else:
        print('2')
```

It also returns '2'

I have no idea what is wrong, has somebody experienced the same issue?

Comment: just do `if isinstance(value, dict):`

Comment: Works for me!. I am not sure what is going wrong on your side. Are you sure your first approach is giving `2`?

Comment: First also returns 1 for me.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle actually I've tried but it throws this error TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types

Comment: You are confusing dict and lists. `values_dict` is a `list`, not a `dict`.

Comment: @AnnaDmitrieva have  you created a variable somewhere else in your code called `dict` as that will have overwritten the inbuilt type of dict

Comment: What I presume is, somewhere along the line, you have named one of your variables `dict` and assigned some values to it. Could you try printing dict?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle  oh damn you are right, thank you!

Comment: If that is the case, try `import builtins; dict = builtins.dict`

Comment: @SayandipDutta thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work - your second code was off slightly. The documentation for [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) can be seen here, and recommends using `isinstance()` for testing the type of an object. The return value of `type` is a type object - not a string, so testing the value of it against a string often yields unexpected results.

```
for v in values_dict:
    if isinstance(v, dict):
        print('1')
    else:
        print('2')
```

**Output:**

```
1
```

Comment: @CDJB How is this approach better from the first one in the question? First approach seems to work fine without any errors.